# Are there any thread safety problems?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, thread-safety

I have this code:

```
public class c1
{
   private List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();

   button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       myObjects.Add(o1);
       button1.Enabled = false;
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
       {
           Thread.sleep(10000);
           myObjects.remove(o1);
           button1.Enabled = true;
       });
   }

   button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       myObjects.Add(o2);
       button2.Enabled = false;
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
       {
           Thread.sleep(10000);
           myObjects.remove(o2);
           button2.Enabled = true;
       });
   }
}
```

o1 and o2 are MyObject which contain the fields ID (long) and Name (String), assume they are initialized, and there are 2 buttons in the form.

Is there any thread safe problem?

Comment: As Alberto said "yes, your code is not thread-safe". Moreover it may even crash  because you access UI controls (buttonX.Enabled = true) from non UI thread (and it's not allowed).

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is threading problem. `button2_click` (so `myObjects.Add(o2)`) can be executed at the same time the first thread (the one started by `button1_click`) is executing (`myObjects.remove(o1)`)

Comment: Updating the `Enabled` property of the `Button` objects in the Task threads is also a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. List is not threadsafe; add & remove using different thread will cause inconsistencies (because behind the list, it was an array);
Use ConcurrentBag